# How to select values from XML type column in oracle 10g

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle10g

Below is my xml column with name xml_col. I want to select all plan names where ProductType is productname and ProductCode is 1111.

```
<life>
 <Holding id="Holding">
<HoldingTypeCode tc="2">Policy</HoldingTypeCode>
<Purpose tc="11">example</Purpose>
<Policy>
  <ProductType tc="235684546454">productname</ProductType>
  <ProductCode>1111</ProductCode>
  <PlanName>name_plan</PlanName>
   </Policy>
 </Holding>
</life>
```

I tried the below simple to select, its not working for me. please help

```
select extractValue(xml_col,'/LifE/Policy/PlanName') "plan" 
FROM mytable
```

to query mt scenario, i have queried as below     which shows an error "ORA-00904: "schemaname"."tablename "."xml_col": invalid identifier"   pls help

```
 select extractValue(xml_col,'/lifE/Holding/Policy/PlanName') "plan name" FROM schemaname.tablename WHERE schemaname.tablename.xml_col.exist('/lifE/Holding/Policy/ProductCode[text()  = "1111"]') = 1
```

Comment: Why the MySQL/Mysqlii tags? How are these products involved, or isn't it Oracle?

Comment: Your `path` is wrong, try `/life/Holding/Policy/PlanName`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were you, I wouldn't use extract or extractvalue, since they're both deprecated since Oracle 10g. Instead, use XMLTABLE, something like:

```
with sample_data as (select xmltype(
'<life>
  <Holding id="Holding">
    <HoldingTypeCode tc="2">Policy</HoldingTypeCode>
    <Purpose tc="11">example</Purpose>
    <Policy>
      <ProductType tc="235684546454">productname</ProductType>
      <ProductCode>1111</ProductCode>
      <PlanName>name_plan</PlanName>
    </Policy>
  </Holding>
  <Holding id="Holding">
    <HoldingTypeCode tc="2">Policy</HoldingTypeCode>
    <Purpose tc="11">example</Purpose>
    <Policy>
      <ProductType tc="235684546454">productname</ProductType>
      <ProductCode>1112</ProductCode>
      <PlanName>name_plan</PlanName>
    </Policy>
  </Holding>
</life>') xml_data from dual)
select xml_data,
       x.*
from   sample_data sd
       cross join xmltable('/life/Holding'
                           passing sd.xml_data
                           columns product_type varchar2(20) path 'Policy/ProductType',
                                   product_code number path 'Policy/ProductCode',
                                   plan_name varchar2(20) path 'Policy/PlanName') x
where  x.product_type = 'productname'
and    x.product_code = 1111;

XML_DATA   PRODUCT_TYPE PRODUCT_CODE PLAN_NAME 
---------- ------------ ------------ ---------
<life>...  productname          1111 name_plan
```

Comment: what is xml_data, sample_data.. i am dealing with only 1 table. could you pls clarify

Comment: I have used the subquery factoring clause (aka `WITH`) to set up a subquery that mimics a table called sample_data, which contains a single column (xml_data) that's of datatype XMLTYPE. It contains a single row. The select at the bottom shows how you would use xmltable to pull data from the xml_data colum in the sample_data "table".

Comment: Query keeps on processing for me.. but not executing :(

Answer (score 3):

@mikron is correct. XML is case sensitive.

```
select extractValue(xml_col,'/life/Holding/Policy/PlanName') "plan" 
FROM mytable
```

EDIT: updated as pointed out by @mikron

Comment: Actually it is not only case sensitiveness. You should also pay attention to the `/Holding` node, it is not listed in your answer. So the correct path is `/life/Holding/Policy/PlanName`

Comment: @mikron thanks. you should have entered that as an answer instead of comment so that the credit can go to you instead. :)

Comment: thank you. but where clause is not working for me. i have edited my question