# questions about XMLTABLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Reference to the thread below, both extract or extractvalue are deprecated, so I selected to use XMLTABLE.
[How to select values from XML type column in oracle 10g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32837957/how-to-select-values-from-xml-type-column-in-oracle-10g)

```
select tr.num_tra,
tr.num_uat,
cd.num_trs,
mm.lib_cau

from HIS_RECD cd
cross join xmltable('/Data/Entity'
                        passing cd.xml_data
                        columns batch_id varchar(20) path 'Key/NUM_TRA') cd
, sat_tran tr
, HIS_COMM mm

where tr.num_tra = cd.batch_id 
and mm.num_trs= cd.num_trs

order by 
cd.batch_id
```

The snippet does work, however, when I add it to a very long
script, I have the error ORA-25156.

ORA-25156: old style outer join (+) cannot be used with ANSI joins.

The existing script is too long to rewrite with ANSI joins. I played around with Oracle SQL Developer's Refactoring-Toggle ANIS/Oracle joins. Somehow it only converted partial script.

```
select tr.num_tra,
tr.num_uat,
cd1.num_trs,
mm.lib_cau

from HIS_RECD cd1, 
                        xmltable('/Data/Entity'
                        passing cd1.xml_data
                        columns batch_id varchar(20) path 'Key/NUM_TRA') cd
, sat_tran tr
, HIS_COMM mm

where tr.num_tra = cd.batch_id 
and mm.num_trs= cd1.num_trs

order by 
cd.batch_id
```

So I was searching for how to avoid cross join and had something above. The snippet works alone too. When inserting it into the long script, the result is empty. Within my knowledge, is it because there are no links between tables cd and cd1?

Answer (score 1):

> ORA-25156: old style outer join (+) cannot be used with ANSI joins.

You can use ANSI and comma joins in the same query - the ANSI joins must be first and the comma joins must be last. (However, it is not considered good practice to mix them - or to use comma joins.)

Your query has two `cd` aliases - you need to call one of them something else.

Given the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE his_recd(num_trs, xml_data) AS
SELECT 1, XMLTYPE('<Data><Entity><Key><NUM_TRA>1234567890</NUM_TRA></Key></Entity></Data>') FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE sat_tran (num_tra, num_uat) AS
SELECT '1234567890', 0 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE his_comm (num_trs, lib_cau) AS
SELECT 1, 0 FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
select tr.num_tra,
       tr.num_uat,
       cd.num_trs,
       mm.lib_cau
from   HIS_RECD cd
       cross join xmltable(
         '/Data/Entity'
         passing cd.xml_data
         columns batch_id varchar(20) path 'Key/NUM_TRA'
       ) x
     , sat_tran tr
     , HIS_COMM mm
where  tr.num_tra = x.batch_id 
and    mm.num_trs= cd.num_trs
order by 
       x.batch_id
```

Which could also be written using ANSI joins as:

```sql
select tr.num_tra,
       tr.num_uat,
       cd.num_trs,
       mm.lib_cau
from   HIS_RECD cd
       cross join xmltable(
         '/Data/Entity'
         passing cd.xml_data
         columns batch_id varchar(20) path 'Key/NUM_TRA'
       ) x
       INNER JOIN sat_tran tr
       ON tr.num_tra = x.batch_id
       INNER JOIN HIS_COMM mm
       ON mm.num_trs= cd.num_trs
order by 
       x.batch_id
```

or only using comma joins:

```sql
select tr.num_tra,
       tr.num_uat,
       cd.num_trs,
       mm.lib_cau
from   HIS_RECD cd
     , xmltable(
         '/Data/Entity'
         passing cd.xml_data
         columns batch_id varchar(20) path 'Key/NUM_TRA'
       ) x
     , sat_tran tr
     , HIS_COMM mm
where  tr.num_tra = x.batch_id 
and    mm.num_trs= cd.num_trs
order by 
       x.batch_id
```

Which all output:

| NUM_TRA | NUM_UAT | NUM_TRS | LIB_CAU |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567890 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

[Oracle 11g fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CwIH0JW2) *[I don't know if you are using Oracle 10g - but its far too old for there to be any online resources to test on that version and you should really upgrade to a newer version.]*

Comment: I tried both adding the long script. The first one I still got ORA-25156: old style outer join (+) cannot be used with ANSI join 
The second one freezes the editor for 20 minutes then I got
Select Error: ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP

Comment: @kebi Search the internet for `ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment` and you will find lots of resources on how to deal with that. However, you may find that your query is missing some of the join conditions so you are doing `CROSS JOIN`s when you should be doing `INNER JOIN`s.

Comment: The best solution for that is to stop using comma-joins and rewrite your query to use ANSI joins and then you can see when you are missing joins. It is much simpler that it seems to rewrite the query - first replace every comma-join with `CROSS JOIN` and then move the join conditions from the `WHERE` clause to the appropriate join and change the join from a `CROSS JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN` (or `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` if all the join conditions use `(+)`).

Comment: Also, the query in the question has no `(+)` joins.